# Какой знак препинания верен?

Tags: пунктуация

"Ты - не умный,ты - глупый.
Ты не умный - ты глупый".
Какой вариант верен ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба верны.

Ты - не умный,ты - глупый.-более экспрессивно, пауза для усиления акцента на местоимении, называющем собеседника.

Ты не умный - ты глупый.-классическая пунктуация.